# Threads in c can't pass function properly to makecontext()

Tags: c, multithreading, parameter-passing

I need to implement a library to work with threads in C.
The user should pass the function of the thread and the argument for it, then
I need to handle and create thread for it.
This is the function to add new thread:

```
    int add_thread(void (*func)(int), int arg) {
    printf("Adding thread #%d with arg:[%d] \n", threadsAdded, arg);
    ////// create the thread.....

    makecontext(&uc[threadsAdded], (void (*)(void)) func, arg);

    More none important things....

}
```

As you can see, the user should pass function with a *void* type, with *int* param and arguments.

So I tried to add this function:

```c
void f2(int n) {
while (1) {
    printf("Thread #%d In progress:\n", n);
}
```

like this:

```c
 add_thread(f2, 1);
 add_thread(f2, 2);
 add_thread(f2, 3);
 add_thread(f2, 199);
```

The problem is, that the argument that the function f2 gets is always -1.
So I just see from all the threads:

> "Thread -1 In progress"

I guess the problem is the way I am passing the arguments to *makecontext()*... Do you see any problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled and found a page that says that the third argument of `makecontext()` should be the number of arguments. ([this is the page](http://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/swapcontext.3.html) for reference. This page is written in Japanese)

Not tested, try this:

```
makecontext(&uc[threadsAdded], (void (*)(void)) func, 1, arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/makecontext.3.html) for `makecontext`:

> ```
>   void makecontext(ucontext_t *ucp, void (*func)(), int argc, ...);
>
>    ...
>
>    The makecontext() function modifies the context pointed to by ucp
>    (which was obtained from a call to getcontext(3)).  Before invoking
>    makecontext(), the caller must allocate a new stack for this context
>    and assign its address to ucp->uc_stack, and define a successor
>    context and assign its address to ucp->uc_link.
> ```

I see no such call to `getcontext()` in your code.  Is your example incomplete?